# My CompletionHandler will not execute. Why?

Tags: swift, uidocument

I have the following code:

```
document?.open { success in
        if success {
            print("file opened")
            self.consumed = self.document?.consumed
        } else {
            print("file read failure")
        }
    }
```

As can be seen, I have a print for both success and failure. But neither prints.

The reasonable question is the file is not there, not readable or something.  Therefore, I have added before this code the following:

```
if document != nil {
        print("not nil")
        let asString = document?.fileURL.path
        let toast = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: asString!)
        if toast {
            print("file exist")
        } else {
            print("file does not exist")
        }
    } else {
        print("nil")
    }
 if FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: (document?.fileURL.path)!)
    {
        print("readable")
    }
    else
    {
        print("not readable")
    }
```

This indicates for me that it is:  not nil, exists, and readable.

Is there sometime I am missing to have this completion code not execute?  It would be great to be able to open the file, but I think the fact that it is not operating is the first step.

Of note about the file.  It is a file that is read from the bundle and copied to Documents directory.  I have looked at the attributes of the file and have found nothing odd.

Comment: The method `open` may be buggy.

Comment: either your `document` is _actually_ `nil` or you are using a _beta_ SDK what cannot be considered reliable because it is _beta_.

Comment: But my test proved it is not nil.

Comment: The code crashes reliably if `document` is `nil`.

Comment: One more additional question.  Could it be an issue with the copy?  I was looking for some from of release to make sure the file is available.  That does not seem to be necessary in Swift.

Regardless, I am suspicious that the copy is not completing or somehow corrupting the file.  However, so far evaluation of attributes shows nothing,

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `document?.open` with `document!.open`, or use a guard let to really make sure document is not nil. Cause if `document` is nil the whole call is being skipped.

[Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) you can read up on Optional Chaining.

Comment: document!.open give no different behavior.  Not sure I know how to use the guard with a completionHandler.

Comment: @jz_ Hm thats weird. The guard would just have checked that document is not nil. What type is document?

Comment: Purpose,document is a JSON file saved as a custom UTI format.  Is that what you are asking.  I guess, one check would be to go back to a JSON ext and read that way,  See if the custom designation is the problem.

Comment: You lost me on UTI format, but if the open does custom opening stuff that could be the culprit too of course.

Comment: Basically you can declare your own extension type.

Comment: And open() parses that for you? If it works by parsing as JSON it could limit the scope of what could have gone wrong.

Comment: If it would execute.  But it does not even begin to execute.  I am following a lecture from the Stanford iTunes series.  Seems to work there, but does not even execute for me.

Comment: @jz_ That sounds pretty frustrating. I found reports from 2013 and 2015 where happened sth similar, but whether its related or not dunno. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177357/discussion-between-jz-and-purpose).